# Insert dash after numbers in vargraphic field

Tags: sql, string, replace, db2, string-formatting

I have a field in a db2 database where I need to modify the string from left column (unformatedName) to right format column (formatedName).

Here's an example:

[image]

What is the best way to find a number in a string and put a dash after the number? The column may have more then one set of numbers. I.E. There can be numbers in the start of the string, in the middle and in the end.

```
SELECT
    locationcode AS unformatedName,
    locationcode AS formatedName
FROM 
    location
WITH UR;
```

Regards

Comment: The number sequence go from 1 to 19, and I don't want to replace 19 to "1-9-"

Comment: You may want to provide some examples of source data and expected results -- your explanation as it is does not make much sense.

Comment: @mustaccio, did you see the screendump I attached? I added that one to add a bit of clarity (hopefully)

Comment: You should add this information to the question itself -- when the external link goes stale, the question without it will be meaningless.

Comment: Besides, your explanation does not correspond to the sample: you don't seem to "replace numbers", but simply insert dashes at fixed positions.

Comment: @mustaccio, you have a point indeed. It's not about replacing numbers, but rather inserting dashes at specific places. In any case does that simplify the tast in any way?

By the way, thanks for adding the screendump to the question! This is my first post here and I thought this was the way to to it.